# Sharing files between Ubuntu and Windows in Qemu?

Tags: qemu

I use Qemu and Virtual Machine Manager to run Windows 10 from my Ubuntu.
I can share data between the two systems by redirecting a USB stick.
Is there an easy way to share a small amount of data without a USB stick?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 18.04..........